# Calculo da Media entre Selects SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Boa Tarde
Por favor me ajudem

> Erro na Síntaxe
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2087
>   Incorrect syntax near 'TAB'.

```
--TARIFAS
--Calcular Média Tarifada 


BEGIN TRY DROP TABLE #TARIFASINDMETRO END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH
SELECT 

        'IND' AS industria,
         PD.[dtt_data_captura],
         AVG(PD.flt_base) AS flt_base, 
         D.[Flt Type], 
         MT.AD,
D.[dtt_data]


    INTO #TARIFASINDMETRO
    FROM #Data D
         INNER JOIN #PreData PD ON PD.GrupoQuery            = D.GrupoQuery AND
                                   PD.[dtt_geracao_ql2]     = D.QTS AND
                                   PD.[vch_empresa_editada] = D.[vch_empresa_editada] AND
                                   --PD.[vch_tipo_arquivo]    = D.[vch_tipo_arquivo] AND
                                   PD.[vch_od]              = D.[vch_od] AND
  PD.[dtt_data]            = D.[dtt_data] AND
                                   PD.[Flt Type]            = D.[Flt Type]

INNER JOIN @Metro MT   ON MT.OC                    = D.[vch_od]                                                                      


WHERE     D.[vch_empresa_editada] IN ('G3','JJ','OC') 


GROUP BY PD.[dtt_data_captura],
         D.[Flt Type], MT.AD, D.[dtt_data]
```

Mas ao fazer o mesmo código mudando o final:
 WHERE     D.[vch_empresa_editada] IN ('G3','JJ','OC') ,

está me trazendo a média da coluna total e não linha a linha.

exemplo

```
                                IND     Média Tarifada 
804.9   669.9   NULL    NULL    592.9   737.4 
804.9   592.9   NULL    NULL    592.9   698.9 
804.9   639.9   NULL    NULL    592.9   722.4 
804.9   529.9   NULL    NULL    592.9   667.4 
804.9   419.9   NULL    NULL    592.9   612.4 
804.9   409.9   NULL    NULL    592.9   607.4
```

A coluna IND é a que preciso inserir e está repetindo. A coluna da média tarifada é o resultado correto (calculo average pelo excel)

Comment: Voc~e poderia nos dar o SQL completo por favor!? pois existem vários parenteses abertos sem terem fechamento, o que impossibilita saber onde o select termina.

Comment: Aparentemente você tem vários SELECTs dentro de GROUP BY, sem fechamento de parenteses. Qual o objetivo desta consulta? Poderia nos dar uma exemplo de resultado desejado. Você está montando esta consulta?

Comment: É muito grande. Existe uma forma de anexar?

Comment: Não precisa anexar. Simplesmente coloque ela aí, que editaremos ela. pois precisamos da consulta toda para saber onde está dando o erro.

Comment: Obrigada, Então agora eu preciso calcular a média tarifada das três G3, JJ, OC para que apareçam em uma nova coluna.

Comment: Bem, vamos por partes. A sua mensagem de erro diz que tem uma sintaxe incorreta perto da palavra TAB, porém esta palavra não consta nessa sua consulta. Logo, presumo que sua consulta seja somente a parte de uma procedure ou um TSQL. Entendi que você quer calcular média tarifada, contudo, isso não é uma operação do banco de dados. portanto diga quais colunas de quais tabelas você deseja calcular a média. E quer que o resultado apareça onde, em qual tabela ou consulta?

Comment: E agora preciso de uma coluna que traga a média dos três. Mas ao fazer o mesmo código mudando o final: WHERE     D.[vch_empresa_editada] IN ('P1','P2','P3') , está me trazendo a média da coluna total e não linha a linha.

Comment: Inclua no seu select o seguinte campo, para assim fazer distinção no cálculo: D.[vch_empresa_editada]

Comment: mantenha a sua clausula WHERE como está e inclua dentro do select este campo usado na cláusula where. Tipo, "select 'IND' as industria, D.[vch_empresa_editada]"

Comment: está me trazendo a média da coluna total e não linha a linha. A coluna IND é a que preciso inserir e está repetindo. A coluna da média tarifada é o resultado correto (calculo average pelo excel) Editei novamente o codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
industria   dtt_data_captura    flt_base    vch_empresa_editada
IND 12/1/2016   1022.15 G3
IND 12/1/2016   1093.4  G3
IND 12/1/2016   950.9   G3
IND 12/1/2016   950.9   G3
IND 12/1/2016   670 JJ
IND 12/1/2016   1733.9  G3
IND 12/1/2016   1029    JJ
IND 12/1/2016   854.9   G3
IND 12/1/2016   854.9   G3
IND 12/1/2016   670 JJ
IND 12/1/2016   854.9   G3

RESOLVIDO: 
Por exemplo, se temos os seguintes dados:

G3  JJ  OC
1   10  18  23
2   20      89
3   30  22  2
teremos as seguintes médias aritméticas, por empresa:

G3  JJ  OC
1   10  18  23
2   20      89
3   30  22  2
média   20  20  38
Se optamos por calcular qual é o valor usando a média aritmética das médias aritméticas, teremos
   (20 + 20 + 38) / 3 = 26

Mas a média aritmética correta é 
  (10 + 18 + 23 + 20 + 89 + 30 + 22 + 2) / 8 = 26,75.

Para calcular média de médias, onde o número de casos de cada média varia, sugiro o uso da média aritmética ponderada:
  ((20 * 3) + (20 * 2) + (38 * 3)) / 8 = 26,75.
```

Comment: Testei, porém a coluna IND que deveria trazer a média calculada entre as três, ainda se repete. Ele não está fazendo o cálculo da linha G3/JJ/OC e sim trazendo uma tarifa média de todos os arquivos, repetindo a mesma tarifa na coluna toda

Comment: Então se a média é calculada entre as 3, você não deveria ter uma tabela para fazer o cálculo da média, é só somar os dados das 3 colunas e dividir por 3. Certo?

Comment: Oi Andrew, olha eu já tentei com função agregada, com store procedure e vários selects. Mas traz sempre o mesmo resultado. A utilização das tabelas temporárias dentro do miolo de código não é possível.

Comment: Editei o último SELECT para tentar me fazer claro, e saber se este é o cálculo possível. Caso contrário, gostaria de saber qual é o SELECT que gera este resultado da consulta final.

Comment: editei o código para que consiga ver o resultado que está me trazendo com a última modificação. Acredito que esteja trazendo a média dos arquivos todos e não realizado o cálculo da media entre as colunas

Comment: Tá, olha só, você entende que você não está postando todo o script envolvido nisso né!? Logo, vamos fazer o seguinte. Põe em um arquivo TXT, todos, eu digo todos os scripts envolvidos; a procedure (acredito que isto seja uma procedure), a consulta que gera o resultado final e um exemplo de dados, se possível um print disso. Põe o print no imgur.com e o TXT sobe num fileshare qualquer.

Comment: Olá bom dia, consegui resolver o problema. Para calcular média de médias, onde o número de casos de cada média varia, usei a média aritmética ponderada.  Em tempo, a função AVG divide a somatória dos valores pelo número de casos, desconsiderando-se ausência de valores (NULL). Por isso não se dividia entre eles e sim do arquivo total. Muito obrigada pela ajuda. Editei com a resposta o script

Comment: Certo. Bem, podia ter informado de maneira mais clara o que você queria, pois realmente ficou bem difícil entender o que realmente era o resultado desejado.